# Is there any way to select the next element by iterating the index of element on CSS without JS?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, element, keyframe

I'm working on animation using SCSS and I was wondering if there's a trick where I don't have to creating different *class* names to programme the animation of those elements individually and **instead** iterate through the element that's next to it rather? No JS.

See the code below for example where I've used the menu bar to appear one after another by delaying the time. It works fine but just imagine if I have a hundred of those menu bars... which  means I would have to write all of that repeatedly...

```
.item-0 {
    animation: 
    appear .3s ease-in forwards,
    moveItemUp .3s ease-in-out forwards; 
}
.item-1 {
    animation: 
    appear .7s ease-in forwards,
    moveItemUp .7s ease-in-out forwards; 
}
.item-2 {
    animation: 
    appear 1s ease-in forwards,
    moveItemUp 1s ease-in-out forwards; 
}
.item-3 {
    animation: 
    appear 1.5s ease-in forwards,
    moveItemUp 1.5s ease-in-out forwards; 
}
```

If I have;

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Banana</div>
  <div class="item">Apple</div>
  <div class="item">Orange</div>
  <div class="item">Coconut</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to apply my Animation @Keyframe to a class *item* where it will iterate through each element in the *list* starting in order from *Banana* down to the last element by delaying 100ms after another?

Thank you

Comment: No there is not

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, There is no way to dynamically calculate css values based on the elements position in the dom

## SCSS workaround

Since you're using SCSS, you could prepare a large chunk of CSS in a loop.
This can be helpful when you know the total elements in advance or can make a reasonable estimate on the maximum amount of items.

### :pseudo selectors

css provices some [tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) to help select the right element. In this case we can use the `:nth-child(1)` selector, where the number 1 represents the index in the list.

### SCCS loop

You can generate chunks of css in a loop

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  .list .item:nth-child(#{$i}) {
     animation: appear 0.3s*$i ease-in forwards, moveItemUp 0.3s*$i ease-in-out forwards; 
 }
}
```

would generate the following:

```
.list .item:nth-child(1) {
  animation: appear 0.3s ease-in forwards, moveItemUp 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.list .item:nth-child(2) {
  animation: appear 0.6s ease-in forwards, moveItemUp 0.6s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.list .item:nth-child(3) {
  animation: appear 0.9s ease-in forwards, moveItemUp 0.9s ease-in-out forwards;
}
```

### fiddle

example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csw421g6/)

Comment: OH WOW! That is amazing!! Thank you soooo much!!! This's answered my question perfectly!!